# Java time: How to interpret time of ISO_DATE_TIME format

Tags: java, java-time

I don't quite figure out what does this date format means:

> 2019-05-01T02:00:00+02:00[Europe/Madrid]

It's formatted using `ISO_DATE_TIME` `DateTimeFormatter`.

The code behind it is:

```
public void meth(Date d) {
    LOG.info(date.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    );
}
```

Does it mean that **in Madrid** time is 00:00:00, or 02:00:00?

I mean, which time are Madrid citizens looking on their clocks?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

The time in Madrid is 02:00:00. `+02:00` is the offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), so the UTC time is 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO standard this constant refers to is ISO 8601 which is also used as format in XML-documents where it's called W3CDTF. The latter is described at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and is a bit easier to understand than the original related standard at [ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/70907.html) and is free instead of the 159 CHF ISO demands...

Concerning your question about the actual time: The time in Madrid is 02:00:00, the timezone information is allowing you to do calculations to other timezone. This is quite common in email as well, where the mail's Date-header contains a date with TZ-info:

> Date: Mon, 1 Apr 2019 12:30:36 +0100

that allows your mail client to show you the mail's date as 13:30:36 if you reside e.g. in Germany and allows you to sort your mail by date correctly.